# Error 403 Forbidden - You tried to access a document for which you don't have privileges

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, servidor, ftp, error-403

Buen día, tengo el siguiente error al cargar mi proyecto no me deja ingresar a esas rutas y me da este error por defecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo asignadas para directorios el permiso 755 y para archivos 644. He probado con varios tutoriales, desde limpiar cache, ver el htacces, he vuelto a revisar el proyecto si tiene todos los archivos volvi a subirlo, confirme que estuvieran todos los archivos, compile localmente mi proyecto y funciona sin ningun inconveniente.

Despues probe con otro proyecto el mismo inconveniente, verifique con mi portafolio que es un simple html y ahi si me funciono solo que para entrar a las rutas de las carpetas me dio el mismo inconveniente pero si me funciono almenos, el que estoy intentando hacer que funcione esta realizado en laravel probé con otro proyecto realizado en CodeIgniter y tampoco siempre con el mismo inconveniente no se que mas podría revisar para verificar cual es el error.

Estoy subiendo los archivos por FTP y estoy utilizando el proveedor de IONOS.

Comment: Intenta de ser mas claro en la explicación, no se entiende bien a que directorios y archivos les diste esos permisos o como, ni que pasó con el .htaccess. También agrega como configuraste el servidor... ¿está apuntando al directorio correcto? Funciona si pones un index.html pero no un index.php? en que directorio? Fijate [este](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#nginx) ejemplo de configuración de nginx, y lo que dice en la documentación > Please ensure, like the configuration below, your web server directs all requests to your application's public/index.php file.

Comment: Son los directorios y archivos que tiene el proyecto a ellos les asigne los permisos que coloque en la descripción del problema, el servidor tiene la configuración habitual de cualquier proveedor de servicios donde lo único que tienes que hacer es subir tus archivos y configurar los accesos para la base de datos, si funciona en archivos php, y si hace las peticiones correctamente a las rutas donde se encuentran los archivos. @porloscerrosΨ